# Transferring sound from a PC to a smartphone via a local network

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, audio-streaming, local-network

I'm just getting acquainted with working with a network and, while studying sockets, I came across different examples of video or audio transmission over a local network, and decided to try to do something similar, namely broadcasting sound from a PC to Android. I use CSCore library to transfer sound from PC. Googling how you can play the sound received over the network on Android, I finally managed to reproduce something, but everything works with strong extraneous noise and is a little interrupted. Now I am in a stupor and do not know where to dig next, can anyone understand this or know a library that can help me with audio playback? Thanks google translate.
PC Application Code:

```
using CSCore.SoundIn;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows;

namespace SendAudio
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        WasapiLoopbackCapture capture;
        UdpClient udpClient;
        IPEndPoint endPoint;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Capture_DataAvailable(object? sender, DataAvailableEventArgs e)
        {
            udpClient.Send(e.Data, e.ByteCount, endPoint);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (BtnStart.Content.ToString() == "Start")
            {
                capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
                capture.Initialize();
                capture.DataAvailable += Capture_DataAvailable;
                waveinfo.Text = $"{capture.WaveFormat.SampleRate}___{capture.WaveFormat.Channels}___{capture.WaveFormat.WaveFormatTag}___{capture.WaveFormat.BytesPerSecond}";
                udpClient = new UdpClient();
                endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IPText.Text), int.Parse(PortText.Text));
                BtnStart.Content = "Stop";
                capture.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                capture.Stop();
                capture.Dispose();
                udpClient.Close();
                udpClient.Dispose();
                BtnStart.Content = "Start";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android app code:

```
using Android.Media;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace GetAudio
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private UdpClient udpClient;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IDEntry.Text = $"{Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0]}";
            PortEntry.Text = "8899";
        }

        private async void GetSound()
        {
            int bufSize = AudioTrack.GetMinBufferSize(100000, ChannelOut.Stereo, Encoding.Pcm16bit);
            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack
                (
                    Android.Media.Stream.Music,
                    100000,
                    ChannelOut.Stereo,
                    Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,
                    bufSize,
                    AudioTrackMode.Stream
                );
            audioTrack.Play();
            while (true)
            {
                var data = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                audioTrack.Write(data.Buffer, 0, data.Buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        private void Play_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            udpClient = new UdpClient(int.Parse(PortEntry.Text));
            GetSound();
        }
    }
}
```

Code with Naudio:

```
private async void Capture_DataAvailable(object? sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(e.Buffer))
            {
                using (var ms3 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (LameMP3FileWriter writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(ms3, capture.WaveFormat, 320))
                    {
                        ms.CopyTo(writer);
                    }
                    byte[] data = ms3.ToArray();
                    await udpClient.SendAsync(data, data.Length, endPoint);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "strong extraneous noise" - are you testing that the data received matches the adta sent - byte for byte?  If it isn't, where is the "noise" coming from?  "little interrupted" - are you buffering the playback?

Comment: Are you testing "live" from a mic? If so, before working on that, take some existing high quality audio sample, and send it over the network. Still noisy?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
I'm trying to transfer sound from a sound card using the WasapiLoopbackCapture class, if I understand correctly. I tried to broadcast the already recorded mp3 file and the noise disappeared, maybe the problem is that I choose the wrong frequency or encoding when playing on my smartphone, but I tried different options.

Comment: Good - you have one situation that works (but doesn't do what you want). Take what works, and what doesn't work, and try to get them "closer together". Given that you've been trying different settings without success, now try the opposite: try to change the "working" solution, so that it has all the same steps as the broken one - get it to break. Am I making sense? Whatever data you tried to broadcast from card, instead save that on the pc, then make an mp3 from that. Is the noise there? Similarly for any other decisions you have to make, such as encoding or frequency...

Comment: ... goal is to "catch" the step in the process where something goes wrong.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I haven't found a way to convert from wav to mp3 using CSCore. I have turned to the NAudio library and using the same class am trying to record and convert on the fly. This gave some results, now the sound is withiut nois, but often intermittent. I have seen similar problems on the internet with Naudio's WasapiLoopbackCapture class, but did not understand how to fix it. At the same time, the WasapiLoopbackCapture CSCore class writes without intermittent, but noisy, problem after problem :D